# how to same variable with different values in different env in terraform module

Tags: variables, terraform

I am using the terraform s3 module https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket. I created a wrapper module around this module for creating a s3 bucket. Currently there are 3 different aws account where in this s3 modules changes should be used for creating the buckets. Since there are 3 different accounts, the grant and the owner values are different for each of the account. Currently, I have hardcoded these value for the buckets that I create

```
s3_bucket.tf

module "sample_bucket" {
  source  = "../../../../modules/aws/data/s3_bucket"
  bucket = "sample_bucket"
  lifecycle_rule = [
     rule here
]
}

>../../../../modules/aws/data/s3_bucket/main.tf file 

module "s3_bucket" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"
  version = "3.6.0"
  bucket = var.bucket
  attach_public_policy = var.attach_public_policy
  server_side_encryption_configuration = var.server_side_encryption_configuration
  grant = var.grant
  owner = var.owner
  cors_rule = var.cors_rule
  lifecycle_rule = var.lifecycle_rule
  tags = var.tags
  versioning = var.versioning 
  replication_configuration = var.replication_configuration
  force_destroy = var.force_destroy
}

> ../../../../modules/aws/data/s3_bucket/variable.tf file 

variable "grant" {
  description = "An ACL policy grant. Conflicts with `acl`"
  type        = any
  default     = []
}

variable "owner" {
  description = "Bucket owner's display name and ID. Conflicts with `acl`"
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}
```

I want to use the grant and the owner variable from the module file in the main.tf file and not hard code these values for each of the accounts in s3_bucket.tf for the buckets I create. Can someone help me here on how to use the same variable `grant` and `onwer` with different values for each of the account

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Terraform Workspaces](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/workspaces) for different environments. An example of how you could use workspaces:

```
module "sample_bucket" {
  source  = "../../../../modules/aws/data/s3_bucket"
  bucket = "sample_bucket"
  grant = "${var.grant}-${terraform.workspace}"
  owner = "${var.owner}-${terraform.workspace}"
  lifecycle_rule = [
     rule here
  ]
}
```

P.S You might have to handle `grant` and `owner` differently from the above code since they are list and map

**Update**:

In case of different folder for each environment, you can define a separate `variables.tfvars` and pass it in as per the need. Read more about Input Variables [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#assigning-values-to-root-module-variables)

Within each folder, you can run and `terraform apply/plan` and it will automatically detect your `terraform.tfvars` file.

```
s3_bucket
│   main.tf
└───dev
│   │   terraform.tfvars
│   │
└───stg
│   │   terraform.tfvars
│   │
└───prod
│   │   terraform.tfvars
│   │
```

Comment: Currently we do not have terraform workspace and might have it in the future. Our current terraform setup is that we have different folders for dev, stg, prod environments. So in this case how can I use grant and owner variables in the module without the workspace for different accounts. Yes, grant and owner are different variables and will be handled differently. However, the requirement is same for both.

Comment: In that case you can use different `.tfvars` file for each of the environment folder. I have updated my answer as well